# Blazor .Net app in Docker Container getting public NuGet dlls but not js or css files

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget, containers

I am running into an issue where I am deploying a Blazor app that contains several public NuGet packages into a Linux Docker container. The container builds properly and adds the appropriate dll files of the packages into `/app` and `/scr`, but it isn't putting the js files into the `wwwroot` folder.

I can reproduce this with a minimal app by:

- starting a new Blazor app with Docker support,
- adding a public NuGet package (in this case, BlazorInputMask)
- adding the calls to _Layout.cshtml for the js files

  - ```
       <script type="text/javascript" src="_content/BlazorInputMask/Main.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="_content/BlazorInputMask/IMask.js"></script>
    ```
- Running the app locally using the Docker debugger
- Checking the Network calls in the browser and seeing a `404 - Main.js` not found
- Checking the files in VS's Docker tools, and navigating to wwwroot, where Main.js and IMask.js are not found.

This works properly when doing a non-containerized build. It's just the container that is the problem.

The problem exists with the scaffolded Dockerfile generated by VS.

I tried laying out a `Nuget.config` file with the following code, but I got the same behavior:

```
<packageSources>
  <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  <add key="wcmMapsSrc" value="." />
</packageSources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the problem!

There is a case mismatch between the NuGet package's docs and code base. In the docs, they reference `Main.js` but the filename is `main.js`.

This never presented a problem in any non-Dockerized deployment we have run, all of which have been Windows-based. However, when run through the Linux container there must be some case-sensitivity added.

Updating my codebase to reference the proper script file name solved the issue.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="_content/BlazorInputMask/main.js"></script>`

Turns out, not a NuGet concern. Leaving this here for others.